# grep information and save as a file readable to Excel?

Tags: excel, csv, awk, grep

I have the following file

```
There is a group of Lion in the forest. There are 3 active. There are 1 sleeping

  Lion1 is talking to Lion2
  Lion2 is talking to Lion3
  Lion3 is touching Lion1

There is a group of Turtle in the forest. There are 1 active. There are 0 sleeping

There is a group of Monkey in the forest. There are 4 active. There are 0 sleeping

  Monkey1 is talking to Monkey3
  Monkey4 is jumping about

There is a group of Panda in the forest. There are 2 active. There are 1 sleeping

There is a group of Owl in the forest. There are 5 active. There are 4 sleeping
```

I used the following command:

```
grep "There is a group" | awk '{print substr($0,10)}'
```

and I get the following

```
Lion in the forest. There are 3 active. There are 1 sleeping
Turtle in the forest. There are 1 active. There are 0 sleeping
Monkey in the forest. There are 4 active. There are 0 sleeping
Panda in the forest. There are 2 active. There are 1 sleeping
Owl in the forest. There are 5 active. There are 4 sleeping
```

**Question**

How should I modify my grep and awk command such that I get the following result:

```
Lion, 3, 1
Turtle, 1, 0
Monkey, 4, 0
Panda, 2, 1
Owl, 5, 4
```

The result will be store into a file that will be read by Microsoft Excel. Inside the Microsoft Excel, I will be able to see three column as follows:

```
===========================
|  Lion       |  3  |  1  |
|  Turtle     |  1  |  0  |
|  Monkey     |  4  |  0  |
|  Panda      |  2  |  1  |
|  Owl        |  5  |  4  |
===========================
```

Appreciate any help render.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the regularity of your data, you could just address the fields directly by replacing:

```
grep "There is a group" | awk '{print substr($0,10)}'
```

with

```
awk -v OFS=', ' '/There is a group/ { print $6, $12, $16 }'
```

Output:

```
Lion, 3, 1
Turtle, 1, 0
Monkey, 4, 0
Panda, 2, 1
Owl, 5, 4
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have edit your answer to make it much clearer

Comment: Jack, you put the `grep` back in there, but you don't need it anymore when you already pattern match in the `awk`.

Comment: @wich. Thanks for the note. I have make some amend to the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked, I've updated the answer to use the output field separator (`OFS`) instead of inserting the commas explicitly.

Comment: @Thor. Cool! Never thought that can actually use the `OFS`.